# display text notification on statusbar of Iphone

Tags: iphone, text, notifications, statusbar

I need to show some text notification on statusbar of jailbreaked iphone , while my app enter background ,does the SBStatusBarController has any method to do this ?or other solution?thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SBStatusBarController` was moved to **`UIStatusBar`** in iOS 4.0. You should look into that.

Comment: you mean UIStatusBar private methods?

Comment: I cann't find any methods ,but found this by google:                                         id sb = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBar];  
    [sb addStatusBarStyleOverrides:4];
    [sb setGlowAnimationEnabled:YES forStyle:4];
    [sb setDoubleHeightStatusText:@"Your text" forStyle:4]; this also seems cann't work out .   any help !

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] addStatusBarStyleOverrides:4];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setGlowAnimationEnabled:NO forStyle:4];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setDoubleHeightStatusText:@"Your text" forStyle:4]; finaly ,this make the double height statusbar,it's red,but the text still is not show ,anything wrong?thanks

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] addStatusBarStyleOverrides:8];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setGlowAnimationEnabled:YES  forStyle:8];
   
UIStatusBar *st =(UIStatusBar *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBar];   [st _setDoubleHeightStatusString:@"test"];                                                  finally,In my applicaiton hook,this works  when ipod stays on home screen,but when I clicked any application icon,that application lanched ,the statusbar maintain same style,but the text disappear.why?any help will be appreciated.thanks.